# Display progress dialog stop Future function

Tags: flutter

I have a Future function "_doSearch" which fetch data from server and it is working fine.
But when I add a another function inside it to display progress dialog while fetching data from the server the progress dialog is displayed but the Future function stop fetching data!!!
Any body can help ?

```
  Future<List<Property>> _doSearch () async{
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return MyProgressDialog("Please wait...");
      }
    );


    Response response = await get("https://www.example.com/services/?action=search");
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      Navigator.pop(context);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      var res = jsonData["results"];

      List<Property> results = [];
      for (var p in res){
        Property unit = Property(p["property_title"], p["property_image"]);
        results.add(unit);
      }
      print(results.length);
      return results;
    }else{
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this method**

```
static progressDialog(bool isLoading, BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(
      content: new Container(
          height: 40.0,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0)),
                new Text("Please wait")
              ],
            ),
          )),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),
    );
    if (!isLoading) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    } else {
      showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WillPopScope(onWillPop: () {}, child: dialog);
        },
        useRootNavigator: true,
      );
    }
  }
```

**example:**

```
Constants.progressDialog(true, context);
Response response = await get("https://www.example.com/services/?action=search");
Constants.progressDialog(false, context);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      var res = jsonData["results"];

      List<Property> results = [];
      for (var p in res){
        Property unit = Property(p["property_title"], p["property_image"]);
        results.add(unit);
      }
      print(results.length);
      return results;
    }
```

Comment: same problem. progress dialog diplayed and stoped http  request

Comment: worked now after updating initstate() function .... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are killing the function using  return MyProgressDialog("Please wait...");

Modify the code like this

```
Future<List<Property>> _doSearch () async{
     
    pr = ProgressDialog(context,type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false);
      pr.style(
          message: 'Please wait...',
          borderRadius: 10.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          progressWidget: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),),
          elevation: 10.0,
          insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          progressTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)
      );

      await pr.show();


    Response response = await get("https://www.example.com/services/?action=search");
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      Navigator.pop(context);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      var res = jsonData["results"];

      List<Property> results = [];
      for (var p in res){
        Property unit = Property(p["property_title"], p["property_image"]);
        results.add(unit);
      }
      print(results.length);
      pr.hide();
      return results;
    }else{
      pr = ProgressDialog(context,type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false);
      pr.style(
          message: 'Please wait...',
          borderRadius: 10.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          progressWidget: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),),
          elevation: 10.0,
          insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          progressTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)
      );

      await pr.show();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Do remember to add and import  `progress_dialog`

Comment: same problem. progress dialog diplayed and stoped http request

Comment: Try printing response status code after
 Response response = await get("https://www.example.com/services/?action=search")
Check if any status code is being displayed..